# Google admin sdk for Google Drive does not return latest results

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I have tried using google admin sdk api for Google Drive. Using the following API

```
https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all/applications/drive
```

But I am not able to retrieve the latest records. When put start date parameter's value to the current date or even a date within a week (5 days to be specific) it does not return any result. (Even if I have just performed an activity or even if activity is one day older.)

Today's Date : 2021-08-14
startTime parameter I submitted: 2021-08-10T11:25:35.663Z

Activity Performed: 1 day ego and also today

Response:

```
{
  "kind": "admin#reports#activities",
  "etag": "\"UU7ZVXZP4ba7JkjgJfj1hAMrbEvzbxchfTG8hqR_ZdI/jyxUe3hRabI2kY-GaFyJclBKHcs\""
}
```